# How to draw 10000 circles in Random locations using JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I'm trying to draw 10,000 circles in JavaFX but it seems like its not working and I'm not even able to draw a single circle. Actually it trows me an error:
[image]

This is the code that I currently have:

```
public class RandomCircles extends Application {

    private Random randomNumbers;
    private int count;
    private final double MAX_X = 600;
    private final double MAX_Y = 300;
    private final int FINAL_CIRCLES = 10000;

    public void start(Stage primaryStage){

        Circle initCircle = new Circle();
        initCircle.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        initCircle.setStrokeWidth(3);
        initCircle.setRadius(1);

        for(count = 0; count <= FINAL_CIRCLES; count++){
            initCircle.setCenterX(randomNumbers.nextInt((int) MAX_X));
            initCircle.setCenterY(randomNumbers.nextInt((int) MAX_Y));
        }

        Group baseDemo = new Group(initCircle);

        // Scene scene = new Scene(baseDemo, MAX_X, MAX_Y);
        Scene scene = new Scene(baseDemo);
        scene.setFill(Color.WHITE);
        scene.getWidth();

        primaryStage.setTitle("10,000");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setResizable(true);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Can somebody also tell me if using the setCenterX/Y is the right approach to create the circles in random locations?

Thanks.

**UPDATE:** To the person who though of my post as a duplicate, it is not. My problem comes from my logic that I implemented in my code not from a NullPointerException(not really) error. , which was wrong. Some guy already helped me to solve it.

Comment: Pasting the error text into your post is much more helpful than a link to the image. Thanks!

Comment: Variable `randomNumbers` is not initialized.

Comment: yes, thats the code, I just changed the class name. The error comes from the for where I'm trying to randomly position the new circles.

Comment: [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) Please explain why you posted an image of the stack trace and the actual code as text.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @Abra most people don't feel comfortable clicking to a different browser tab just to check X file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After fixing the runtime error you are getting, your code only draws one circle. That's because you only add one circle to your scene graph. The `for` loop basically does nothing. The last X and Y coordinates for the circle's center are used to draw the single, solitary circle. You need to add ten thousand circles.

In the code below, I changed 10_000 to 100 (one hundred) since 10_000 has too many overlapping circles in the stage dimensions that you set. I also increased each circle's radius.

```java
import java.util.Random;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class RandomCircles extends Application {
    private Random randomNumbers = new Random();
    private int count;
    private final double MAX_X = 600;
    private final double MAX_Y = 300;
    private final int FINAL_CIRCLES = 100;

    public void start(Stage primaryStage){
        Group baseDemo = new Group();
        for(count = 0; count <= FINAL_CIRCLES; count++){
            Circle initCircle = new Circle();
            initCircle.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
            initCircle.setStrokeWidth(3);
            initCircle.setRadius(5);
            initCircle.setCenterX(randomNumbers.nextInt((int) MAX_X));
            initCircle.setCenterY(randomNumbers.nextInt((int) MAX_Y));
            baseDemo.getChildren().add(initCircle);
        }

        Scene scene = new Scene(baseDemo);
        scene.setFill(Color.WHITE);
        scene.getWidth();

        primaryStage.setTitle("100");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setResizable(true);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

`private Random randomNumbers;`

to this:

`private Random randomNumbers = new Random();`

Your code is assuming the the Random object will be allocated like the other member variables, but it is an object and must be created with new.

Comment: Yes, I would say so, the error youre talking about comes from the inside the circle where I'm trying to randomly position the 'generated'(if there actually any) circles